# While executing the report macro based report and getting error "Subscript out of range"

Tags: excel, vba

The script is running in Citrix [VDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_virtualization#Remote_desktop_virtualization) login, but it is getting an error in AWS login. I tried all the options as per Stack Overflow guidance and still the issue is coming.

Here is the code:

This particular code will copy the data from the input sheets and extract the data in new workbook with five individual tabs.

```
Dim CurBookName As String
Dim NewBookName As String
Dim sServerName As String


Private Sub CheckBox1_Change()

    'If checkbox is checked, all the products in the listbox will be selected. If checkbox is unchecked
    'all the products in the listbox will be deselected.

    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
            ListBox1.Selected(i) = True
        Next
    ElseIf CheckBox1.Value = False Then
        For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
            ListBox1.Selected(i) = False
        Next
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    'This code creates new Workbook and adds required Worksheets to it

    On Error GoTo errHandler

        Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
        Dim bSelFlag As Boolean
        Dim sFormula As String
        Dim sVersion As String
        Dim sPath As String
        Dim sRepVerVal As String, sComVerVal As String

        bSelFlag = False

        For j = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
            If ListBox1.Selected(j) = True Then
                bSelFlag = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j

        If bSelFlag = False Then
            MsgBox "Please select one or more products from the product list"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        CurBookName = ActiveWorkbook.name

        For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1

            If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then

                SetMenuParameters (i)

                ' 1. Create blank workbook
                ' 2. Copy all format to new workbook
                ' 3. Copy all value to new workbook

                Workbooks.Add


                NewBookName = ActiveWorkbook.name

                Workbooks(NewBookName).Worksheets.Add().name = "Total Summary"
                Workbooks(NewBookName).Worksheets.Add().name = "Flow"
                Workbooks(NewBookName).Worksheets.Add().name = "Variance"
                Workbooks(NewBookName).Worksheets.Add().name = "TBA"
                Workbooks(NewBookName).Worksheets.Add().name = "Percentage"
                Workbooks(NewBookName).Worksheets.Add().name = "Total"

                Application.DisplayAlerts = False

                Workbooks(NewBookName).Worksheets("sheet1").Delete
                Workbooks(NewBookName).Worksheets("sheet2").Delete
                Workbooks(NewBookName).Worksheets("sheet3").Delete

                Application.DisplayAlerts = True

                Windows(CurBookName).Activate

                Application.StatusBar = "Please wait....Copy Process is in progress for the Product '" & ListBox1.List(i) & "' ..."

                CopySheet "Total Input", "Total"
                CopySheet "Price Input", "Percentage"
                TBA_Built = False

                CopySheet "TBA", "TBA"
                Var_Built = False

                CopySheet "Variance", "Variance"
                CF_Built = False

                CopySheet "Flow", "Flow"
                CopySheet "Total Summary", "Total Summary"

                sVersion = Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("CreateSnapshot").Cells(9, 8).Value

                sPath = "\\user\shunt\"

                If val(Application.Version) > 11 Then
                    Call Hide_Rows_Snapshot(NewBookName, "Percentage")
                    NewBookName = "TM1 " & ListBox1.List(i) & " TBA (" & sVersion & ")_" & Format(Now(), "MMDDYYHHMMSS") & ".xlsx"
                ElseIf val(Application.Version) = 11 Then
                    NewBookName = "TM1 " & ListBox1.List(i) & " TBA (" & sVersion & ")_" & Format(Now(), "MMDDYYHHMMSS") & ".xls"
                End If

                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=sPath & Replace(NewBookName, "/", "_")

                ActiveWindow.Close
            End If
        Next

        MsgBox "Copy Process has been done successfully!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please find the Snapshots at " & sPath

        Application.StatusBar = ""

    Exit Sub

    errHandler:

        MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

    'This code populates TBA products
    Dim iMonth As Integer, iYear As Integer, sYear As Integer
    Dim sMonth As String, sVersion As String, sVerFormula As String
    Dim sVarVersion As String, sVarVerFormula As String

    PopulateProducts

    iYear = Format(Date, "yyyy")
    sMonth = Format(Date, "mmm")
    sMonthnum = Month(Date)

    If sMonth = "Jan" Or sMonth = "Apr" Or sMonth = "Jul" Or sMonth = "Oct" Then
        sMonthnum = sMonthnum + 1
        sYear = iYear
    ElseIf sMonth = "Mar" Or sMonth = "Jun" Or sMonth = "Sep" Then
        sMonthnum = sMonthnum + 2
        sYear = iYear
    ElseIf sMonth = "Dec" Then
        sMonthnum = sMonthnum - 10
        iYear = iYear + 1
        sYear = iYear
    Else
        sMonthnum = sMonthnum
        sYear = iYear
    End If

    sMonth = MonthName(sMonthnum, True)
    sVersion = sMonth & "_" & Mid(CStr(iYear), 3, 2) & "_Forecast"

    'Setting default values to Report Parameters

    Worksheets("CreateSnapshot").Cells(9, 8) = sVersion

    sServerName = Worksheets("Globals").Range("Server_Name").Value
    sVerFormula = "SUBNM(" & """" & sServerName & ":Version""" & "," & """" & """,""" & sVersion & """)"
    Worksheets("CreateSnapshot").Cells(9, 8).Formula = "=" & sVerFormula

    Worksheets("CreateSnapshot").Cells(10, 8) = Format(Date, "yyyy") - 1

    'Setting default values to Variance Parameters

    iMonth = Month(Now)
    iYear = Year(Now)
    iYear = Format(Date, "yyyy")

    iMonth = sMonthnum

    If iMonth = 2 Then
        If iYear <> sYear Then
            iMonth = 11
        Else
            iMonth = 11
            iYear = iYear - 1
        End If
    Else
        iMonth = iMonth - 3
    End If

    sVarVersion = MonthName(iMonth, True) & "_" & Mid(CStr(iYear), 3, 2) & "_Forecast"

    Worksheets("CreateSnapshot").Cells(9, 11) = sVarVersion
    sVarVerFormula = "SUBNM(" & """" & sServerName & ":Version""" & "," & """" & """,""" & sVarVersion & """)"
    Worksheets("CreateSnapshot").Cells(9, 11).Formula = "=" & sVarVerFormula
End Sub


Public Sub PopulateProducts()

    'The listbox is populated with Products from TBA_Products subset

    Dim SubsetSize As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim ElName As String

    SubsetSize = Application.Run("SUBSIZ", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(GLOBALS).Range("Server_Name") & ":Product", "TBA_Products")
    ListBox1.Clear

    i = 1
    While i <= SubsetSize

        ElName = Application.Run("SUBNM", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(GLOBALS).Range("Server_Name") & ":Product", "TBA_Products", i, "Description")
        ListBox1.AddItem (ElName)
        i = i + 1
    Wend

    ListBox1.Height = 220
    ListBox1.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti

End Sub


Private Sub CopySheet(SourceSheetName As String, TargetSheetName As String)
    'This code copies all the data from source workbook to target workbook
    Dim ProdName As String

    On Error Resume Next
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets(SourceSheetName).Activate

        Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets(SourceSheetName).Cells.Copy

        Workbooks(NewBookName).Worksheets(TargetSheetName).Activate

        Workbooks(NewBookName).Worksheets(TargetSheetName).Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

        Workbooks(NewBookName).Worksheets(TargetSheetName).Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
               :=False, Transpose:=False

        'Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets(SourceSheetName).Range("B2").CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap

        ProdName = Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets(MENU).Range("Input_Product").Value

        Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets(SourceSheetName).Shapes(ProdName).Copy

        Workbooks(NewBookName).Worksheets(TargetSheetName).Range("B1:B3").PasteSpecial

        Worksheets(TargetSheetName).Shapes(ProdName).Left = Worksheets(TargetSheetName).Columns("B").Left
        Worksheets(TargetSheetName).Shapes(ProdName).Top = Worksheets(TargetSheetName).Rows(1).Top
        Worksheets(TargetSheetName).Shapes(ProdName).Height = Worksheets(TargetSheetName).Rows(4).Top - Worksheets(TargetSheetName).Rows(1).Top

        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 70

        Workbooks(NewBookName).Worksheets(TargetSheetName).Columns("A").Hidden = True

        Workbooks(NewBookName).Worksheets(TargetSheetName).Range("E1").Select

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Sub SetMenuParameters(iVal As Integer)

    'Input parameters and Report parameters are being set here

    'Input Parameters
    sServerName = Worksheets("Globals").Range("Server_Name").Value

    Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("Menu").Range("Input_Product").Value = ListBox1.List(iVal)
    sFormula = "SUBNM(" & """" & sServerName & ":Product""" & "," & """TBA_Products""" & "," & iVal + 1 & "," & """Description""" & ")"
    Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("Menu").Cells(8, 4).Formula = "=" & sFormula

    Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("Menu").Cells(5, 4).Value = Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("CreateSnapshot").Cells(7, 8).Value
    Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("Menu").Cells(5, 4).Formula = Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("CreateSnapshot").Cells(7, 8).Formula

    Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("Menu").Cells(6, 4).Value = Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("CreateSnapshot").Cells(8, 8).Value
    Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("Menu").Cells(6, 4).Formula = Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("CreateSnapshot").Cells(8, 8).Formula

    Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("Menu").Cells(7, 4).Value = Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("CreateSnapshot").Cells(9, 8).Value
    Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("Menu").Cells(7, 4).Formula = Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("CreateSnapshot").Cells(9, 8).Formula

    Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("Menu").Cells(9, 4).Value = Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("CreateSnapshot").Cells(10, 8).Value

    'Report Parameters

    Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("Menu").Range("Report_Product").Value = ListBox1.List(iVal)
    sFormula = "SUBNM(" & """" & sServerName & ":Product""" & "," & """TBA_Products""" & "," & iVal + 1 & ", " & """Description""" & " )"
    Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("Menu").Cells(19, 4).Formula = "=" & sFormula

    Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("Menu").Cells(16, 4).Value = Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("CreateSnapshot").Cells(7, 8).Value
    Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("Menu").Cells(16, 4).Formula = Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("CreateSnapshot").Cells(7, 8).Formula

    Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("Menu").Cells(17, 4).Value = Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("CreateSnapshot").Cells(8, 8).Value
    Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("Menu").Cells(17, 4).Formula = Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("CreateSnapshot").Cells(8, 8).Formula

    Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("Menu").Cells(18, 4).Value = Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("CreateSnapshot").Cells(9, 8).Value
    Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("Menu").Cells(18, 4).Formula = Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("CreateSnapshot").Cells(9, 8).Formula

    Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("Menu").Cells(20, 4).Value = Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("CreateSnapshot").Cells(10, 8).Value

    'Variance Parameters

    Var_Built = True

    Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("Variance").Cells(4, 8).Value = Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("CreateSnapshot").Cells(7, 11).Value
    Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("Variance").Cells(4, 8).Formula = Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("CreateSnapshot").Cells(7, 11).Formula

    Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("Variance").Cells(5, 8).Value = Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("CreateSnapshot").Cells(8, 11).Value
    Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("Variance").Cells(5, 8).Formula = Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("CreateSnapshot").Cells(8, 11).Formula

    Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("Variance").Cells(6, 8).Value = Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("CreateSnapshot").Cells(9, 11).Value
    Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("Variance").Cells(6, 8).Formula = Workbooks(CurBookName).Worksheets("CreateSnapshot").Cells(9, 11).Formula
End Sub


Private Sub Hide_Rows_Snapshot(NewBookName As String, TargetSheetName As String)

    Dim UsedRows As Integer
    Dim UseRange As String

    Workbooks(NewBookName).Activate

    With ActiveWorkbook
        UsedRows = .Worksheets(TargetSheetName).UsedRange.Rows.Count
        UseRange = "A1:A" & Trim(str(UsedRows))

        For Each c In .Worksheets(TargetSheetName).Range(UseRange).Cells
            If c.Value = "hide" Then
                .Worksheets(TargetSheetName).Rows(c.Row).Hidden = True
            Else
                .Worksheets(TargetSheetName).Rows(c.Row).Hidden = False
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Please include your code, and tag the question properly

Comment: hi James, any suggestions? or findings?

Comment: Please include in which line of code you get the error massage. Looks like you posted *all* your code, see [mcve] and try to narrow it down to the actual issue. We need a good error description in order to help you.

Comment: Re `On Error GoTo errHandler`: What is this? [Visual Basic 6.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic#Timeline)? Is that necessary in VBA?

Comment: @shunt When you get the error if you have an option to debug which line is highlighted. If you don't get an option try removing On Error Goto errHandler. You might also want to remove On Error Resume Next.

Answer (score 0):

All `Subscript Out of Range` means is that your array doesn't have the member you are requesting.

```
dim v(5) as variant
v(0) = 'dog'
v(1) = 'cat'
v(2) = 'fish'
v(3) = 42
v(4) = 3.14
debug.print v(4) // Output is 3.14
debug.print v(5) //Throws Subscript out of range error.
```